# Runtime Error In Python Couldnt able to solve while submiting on the codeChef

Tags: python

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains two space-separated integers N and K denoting the number of measurements and the number of the greatest and the lowest values that will be removed.
The second line contains N space-separated integers A1, A2, ..., AN denoting the measurements.

For each test case, output a single line containing the average value after removing K lowest and K greatest measurements.

```
var1=int(input("t:"))

while var1:

    list1=[]

    var2=int(input("n"))
    var3=int(input("k"))

    for i in range(var2):
        list1.append(int(input())) 

    list1.sort()

    print(list1)

    for i in range(var3):
        f=len(list1)
        list1=list1[1:f-1]

    sumOfList=sum(list1)

    total=0
    number=var2-(2*var3)
    total=sumOfList/number
    print("%.6f"%total)
    var1-=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var2=int(input("n"))
```

will read the entire line of input and then attempt to convert it to an integer. The first line of each test case consists of 2 space separated integers, so `input()` will return the complete line including *both* numbers, e.g. if the second line of the input file contained

```
1 2
```

then `input()` would return the string `1 2`. Trying to convert that to an integer with `int()` will fail:

```
>>> int('1 2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2'
```

You can read the line, split it, and convert each item to an integer like this:

```
n, k = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

There is a similar problem when trying to read in the second line of each test case, which is a space separated list of numbers. You can fix that with this:

```
numbers = sorted(int(x) for x in input().split())
```